# How do you maintain protocol of function return value in dynamic language?

Tags: design, interfaces

In dynamic programming language like Python, Javascript,
it's very easy to make a function return an object:

```
def make_vector2(a, b):
    return {"x": a, "y": b}
```

The 'signature' of the returned object from `make_vector2` acts as a protocol or interface to other functions.
For example:

```
def norm(v):
    return math.sqrt(v["x"]**2 + v["y"]**2)
```

During the evolution of a program, there may be changes on the signature of the returned object.
For example, I would change above vector definition to `{"x0": a, "x1":b}`.

This protocol change may invalidate its related functions(i.e. `norm` in above example).

In static programming language, I have compiler help me to keep the protocol consistent.
While in dynamic programming language I cannot detect the problems unless I actually run the code.

Is there any suggestions/good tools for this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

People who prefer dynamic languages don't consider this to be a problem in the first place.  the basic tools used to deal with this are simply good testing.  Yes, you cannot detect a problem such as you describe without running the code, so the key is to run the code through a good test-suite, probably as often as you compile.

There are disadvantages to this, of course.  If code doesn't get tested, the error goes undetected whereas a compiler would have caught it.  But what you lose there, you gain in speed of development, and the ability to use looser coupling.

Your code will of course throw when `norm` is called.  So if you run a basic test suite that calls `norm` with the results of `make_vector2` at least once, you'll catch the error.  If you run those tests as often as you would compile a C++ or Java program, then it really makes no difference.  Either way, the bug gets caught.

The other part of the answer is to try to design the code in a way that the contract is more clear.  For example:

```
class Vector:
    def __init__(self,x,y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

def make_vector2(a, b):
    return Vector(a,b)

def norm(v):
    return math.sqrt(v.x**2 + v.y**2)
```

That still has to be tested the same way as the original code, of course, but this documents the protocol in a way that the earlier version doesn't.  It means that you can do a `help(make_vector2)` and see that it returns a `Vector` object with an `x` and a `y` attribute.  This makes the error less likely in the first place.

In general, returning raw dictionaries is best when you are intentionally keeping things loosely coupled and therefore can handle more variant contents.

Answer (score 3):

One approach is to use a software contract system, specifically one with support for function contracts and higher-order function contracts. The general idea is you use contract-creation tools to wrap a function with rules that specify "I accept these kinds of values and return this kind of value." It's similar to a type system, except checked dynamically. The most prominent implementation of such a system can be found in the language Racket, though implementations exist for other dynamic languages including JavaScript and Python.