# Function returning dynamic value

Tags: design, python, programming-practices, patterns-and-practices

Imagine you have a chain of functions calls, in which each function is taking the previous function's output as input for the next calculation in the chain.

Make an assumption that you are leading the infra scope, which means you are defining the process chain and protocol, but you have a group of users that are responsible to implement each cube of the chain (I.e implementation of functions `A`,`B`,`C` and so forth).

Assume we have already a given flow like`A->B->C->D`, now imagine that function `A` sometimes need to return a `dictionary` and sometimes `pandas dataframe` as input, this is requirement came from the users, and I think quite break common programming paradigms.

In my opinion, this can have serious inconsistency issues, errors and less testable code.

**I would like to hear your thoughts regarding this as a concept**
Do you think it is reasonable to return different value type from function according to configuration and having protocol in which each cubes in chain may not talking always on the same protocol?
(Discliamer: We are using `python`)

I tend to see this equivalent to the ability, for example, to populate function parameter function with different types for the same **parameter** let say (I.e sometimes int sometimes dict) at different function calls - which is wrong.

Although a dynamic type language might let you do it, it's doesn't necessarily  mean you should do it, and it may be considered as a bad practice or even abuse of the ability.

Even in python the use of dynamic parameters passing (*args, **kwargs) should be used wisely and in a limited way and only when needed for example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14626279/inheritance-best-practice-args-kwargs-or-explicitly-specifying-parameters)

Comment: see [What is the problem with "Pros and Cons"?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6758/31260)

Comment: No more pros and cons, but this channel is for exchanging ideas and more broader view, engineering concepts, I see no contradiction now, this may be relevant to `stackoverflow` when trying to be as specific as possible

Comment: I doubt this, see [On discussions and why they don't make good questions](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6742/31260)

Comment: And the following isn't discussion ?https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/154733/my-boss-decided-to-add-a-person-to-blame-field-to-every-bug-report-how-can-i/154741#154741

Is it a more legitimate question than mine? :)

Comment: Isn't this just [duck typing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing)?  It's a pretty common and useful feature.

Comment: @Mulder Historical questions are not a guide for what makes a good, on-topic question on this site.  The scope of this site and indeed the name of this site has changed since that question had been asked over 7 years ago.   That particular question would almost certainly be closed as off-topic if it were asked here now in 2019 because the topic is covered on https://workplace.stackexchange.com/ instead

Comment: @BenCottrell: it's software engineering concept question, I don't think it will be suitable in general workspace exchange, please refer me to another suitable option.
Btw see another - more fresher question in the same manner:https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/276386/how-do-you-maintain-protocol-of-function-return-value-in-dynamic-language

Comment: And... another good/bad practice question - from **7 months ago**.. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/388905/what-is-a-good-method-practice-i-can-employ-to-keep-identical-code-snippits-in-t?rq=1

Comment: @Mulder As I said, other questions are not a guide for what makes a good, on-topic question on this site.    Some questions may be closed if they aren't a good fit, many others will fall through the net.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is overall a bad practice. Functional language or not, `function` as a concept should have a given, proper set of inputs (or a single one) and the same for the output, stemming from a mathematical definition of a function. Functional languages bridge this issue of inconsistent return types in chains through the use of [monads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2704652/monad-in-plain-english-for-the-oop-programmer-with-no-fp-background), which neatly wrap the resulting type in a "container", allowing for easier handling in such calls.

Specific to this case, why wouldn't all of your functions *talk on the same protocol*?  Having a configuration flag indicating which protocol to switch to for all functions doesn't seem like a bad idea, but if some functions are "deaf" in regards to listening to what the configuration says, then you're in for a wild ride of error handling and matching input types. I'd certainly avoid that if possible and I'd always return the same type, avoiding that conf-based function **definition** as well, for example in your case, I'd always return a dict with the Int value inside it under some specific key.

There's a reason for Python having a practice of docblock-ing functions stating the return type of that function. I'd reformat the code to follow established practices, most likely it'll save you some effort in the long run.